# How can I add a directory path to i386mingw-g++?

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

How can I add a directory path to i386mingw-g++? I am working under Linux.

When I try to cross-compile a .cpp program with i386mingw-g++, it does not take the path of the include directories.

In the help, it instructs me to use the `-B` option, but if I use that, I get this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add new directories to the include-search path by passing them to gcc/g++ using *-I* option.
For Example:

```
# search for headers in the current directory
# as well as in in /usr/local/mingw/include 

i386mingw-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/mingw/include -c myfile.cpp -o myfile.o
```

If you're using makefiles to build your project you can look for a variable called *CFLAGS* or *CXXFLAGS* and add your include statements there. Most makefiles use these variables to store global compiler options.

There is a good makefile howto available at [metalshell](http://www.metalshell.com/view/tutorial/120/).

In addition the *-B* option you mention is defined as follows:

> -Bprefix
>      *This option specifies where to find the executables, libraries,
>
>      include files, and data files **of the compiler itself.***

As long as you're not using a hand-copied installation of gcc it should be able to find those files without explicit *-B prefix_of_my_gcc_install*.

Hope this helps.